# asp.net mvc routing catch /{sometoken}

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, routes

There is a website at http://www.example.com/ which should respond to http://www.example.com/{sometoken} . Where {sometoken} is a string of length 6 .

How do I write routes.MapRoute to map all requests for {sometoken} to the " Controller1/GetIdAction?sometoken={sometoken}" .

This is how I tried and it didn't work, what did I do wrong?

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                "TokenRoute",
                "{someToken}",
                new { controller = "Controller1", action = "GetIdAction" },
                new { someToken = "^[a-f0-9]{6}$" }
                );
```

Comment: If you're passing it as a query parameter ("?sometoken=foobar") you don't need to explicitly declare that in route.

Comment: No need to use `MapRoute` for URL with query string (only for URL with slashes). The mechanics to convert URL with query string to URL with slashes is called URL rewriting (usually configured in web.config or IIS).

Comment: Thank You @TetsuyaYamamoto . It worked with web.config. I wasn't aware of this. Very good solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is URL rewrite and should be configured in web.config.

```
<system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="someToken">
        <match ignoreCase="false" url="^([a-f0-9]{6})$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="Controller1/GetIdAction?someToken={R:1}" />      
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Thank You @TetsuyaYamamoto for the solution.